# unable to align some of the text-fields

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment

Here is the design for the shot i have posted :

```
<div id=site_content>
<div id = left_content>
<table>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <h1> First Name </h1> </td>
                                <td> <input type="text" name="FirstName" /> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <h1> Last Name </h1> </td>
                                <td> <input type="text" name="LastName"/> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <h1> Email </h1></td>
                                <td> <input type="email" name="Email"/> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <h1> Password </h1> </td>
                                <td> <input type="password" name="Password"/> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <h1> Retype Password </h1> </td>
                                <td> <input type="password" name="RetypedPassword"/> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"> <center> <input type="submit" value="submit" /> </center> </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
      </div></div>
```

[image]

Though i tried to align them,but couldn't do enough. If you notice the *Retype Password* field it is not properly aligned. And others if we notice carefully they are also not. How can i align them ,i a regular fashion.

CSS :

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
  font: normal 200% 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;}

#site_content { 
 width: 950px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 4px auto 0 auto;
 padding: 0;}

#left_content { 
 float: left;
 text-align: justify;
 width: 444px;
 padding: 20px 0 5px 25px;
 margin: 0;}
```

Comment: Please post the corresponding CSS. That's where (most likely) is the problem.

Comment: `<td align="(left|center|right)">` ? Or if you mean vertical align `<td valign="(top|middle|bottom)">`

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the fiddle for output/code and demo

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uDL8K/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uDL8K/embedded/result/

Comment: Thanks for the compliment and i m happy to solve you problem. Gud Day.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a 15px bottom margin on `h1` elements. Set it to zero instead. Better still, drop the semantically all wrong `h1` markup here (they are field labels, not first-level headings), use `label` instead and don’t set their margin at all.

Especially if you use very large (200%) font size for the labels, set some extra spacing between the longest label and the input field. Using `label`, you could just set some right padding for it.

Answer (score 0):

heading css should be like this.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
  font: normal 200% 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', arial, sans-serif;
}
```